# Big Commerce API Put call inside VBA

Tags: vba, api, excel, bigcommerce

I have an excel sheet which is doing some matching from Quickbooks (hence the Excel).

I know I can pass "PUT" and "GET" calls using DOM and XMLHTTP but when I send the PUT I get the message back:

A content type for the input was not supplied.

Is this a syntax issue on my part?  I've tried a few ways:

```
/api/v2/products/33288?"Content-Type":"application/json"&"condition":"Worn"

/api/v2/products/33288?"condition":"Worn"

/api/v2/products/33288,"condition":"Worn"
```

All with similar results.

If it doesn't show, I am not all that comfortable with API calls, but very comfortable with VBA

Full Code

```
Dim req As New XMLHTTP
Dim doc As New DOMDocument

Dim url As String
Dim nd As String

url = "https://USER:PASS@WEBSITE/api/v2/products/33288?""Content-Type"":""application/json""&""condition"":""Worn"""

req.Open "PUT", url, False
req.Send

doc.LoadXML req.ResponseText
doc.Save "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\WebQueryResult2.xml"
```

Comment: I updated the question with the full code

Comment: Yes, syntax issue. `Content-Type` is a header, not a URL parameter (it does not belong nor get set in the URL). Maybe - `req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"` ?